# BitmapIcon forecolor in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

When I try to set a custom icon in `NavigationViewItem` using `<BitmapIcon>` it shows the icon only in white or black, even the png with color. is there a way to fix that?

Here is my code:

```
<NavigationViewItem Content="Local">
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Items/MediaOptions/local_icon.png"   Height="40" Width="40"/>
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

**Here the image**

[image]

**Here how it looks**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the document [BitmapIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon?view=winrt-22621#remarks),

> All color info is stripped from the bitmap when the BitmapIcon is
> rendered. The remaining non-transparent colors are combined to produce
> an image that's entirely the foreground color as set by the Foreground
> property (this typically comes from styles or templates, such as the
> default template resolving to a theme resource). You can override this
> behavior by setting the **ShowAsMonochrome** property.

You can set [BitmapIcon.ShowAsMonochrome Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon.showasmonochrome?view=winrt-22621) to false to get full color.

```
<BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets\local_icon.png"  ShowAsMonochrome ="False"  Height="40" Width="40"/>
```